# Writing each record to a file bpel file adapter

Tags: xml, soa, bpel

I have a requirement to write each record from a table to a XML file. I can think of the below solution

Have a DB adapter to query the records from Table
Put a loop for the DB output collections and invoke transformation (by passing parameters , usually the iterator value) to write the nth record to File input variable
Write the file with dynamic file name passed (usually with a value of a column in the table record)
Repeat for next record to create another file

But I personally don't like this approach and I am just trying to find if there is any best approach available to do the same? I have to use only BPEL to do this.

Thanks and feel free to ask for further clarifications required

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you don't wish to select all the records from db in a single go and iterate it for writing to file. If that is the case, have you thought about below approach ?

1. Select the total count of records satisfying your selection criteria(select (count(id) from table1 where myCondition1)) and keep it in
   a bpel variable, say TOTALCNT.
2. Declare bpel variable START=1.
3. Declare a bpel variable END = 50.Lets say there are 1000 records in DB satisfying our condition,we will be selecting only 50 records
   at a time from DB and write it to file.
4. Now fire the selection query for selecting the data(select field1,field2,... fieldn from table1 where myCondition1 AND ROWNUM >=START AND ROWNUM <= END ). This will give you the first 50 records matching the selection criteria. START and END will be passed to
   adapter from bpel flow.
5. Write these records to file after your transformations.
6. Check if END < TOTALCNT. If yes, SET START = END and increment END by 50, for selecting the next 50 records. And go to Step 4.Repeat this process till END >= TOTALCNT.

Check this link for ROWNUM- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Hi Habin, Thanks for your reply. But my requirement is to write each record to a new file. I wanted to avoid frequent DB hits, so i want to select all the records in one go (maximum records will be less than 100) and then write each record to a new file. So at the end i will have 100 files for 100 records.